# How to differentiate two segmented Controls?

Tags: iphone, events

Does anybody know how to check what segmented Control has triggered the event? I am creating two cells which contain segmented Controls. In the method segmentedControlIndexChanged I want to know which segmented Control has triggered the event. I used tag, but it isn't working. I am new with this. I would appreciate your help.

The Code for the cells, which contain segmented Controls:

```
 cellParinti = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cellParinti.textLabel.text = @"Parinti";
cellParinti.label.text = dog?dog.parinti:@"";
cellParinti.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [dog.parinti isEqualToString:@"da"] ? 0 : 1;
cellParinti.segmentedControl.tag = 1;
[cellParinti.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cellParinti addSubview:cellParinti.textLabel];
[cellParinti addSubview:cellParinti.label];
[cellParinti addSubview:cellParinti.segmentedControl];


cellPedigree = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
cellPedigree.textLabel.text = @"Pedigree";
cellPedigree.label.text = dog?dog.pedigree:@"";
cellParinti.segmentedControl.tag = 2;
cellPedigree.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = [dog.pedigree isEqualToString:@"da"] ? 0 : 1;
[cellPedigree.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[cellPedigree addSubview:cellPedigree.textLabel];
[cellPedigree addSubview:cellPedigree.label];
[cellPedigree addSubview:cellPedigree.segmentedControl];
```

The code for the method, which has been triggered:

```
-(void) segmentedControlIndexChanged:(id)sender{
NSIndexPath *indexPath;

UISegmentedControl * sg1 = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

// reload data based on the new index
if (sg1.tag == 1){
cellParinti.label.text = sg1.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? @"da" : @"nu";
dog.parinti = sg1.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? @"da" : @"nu";
}
else {
    cellPedigree.label.text = sg1.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? @"da" : @"nu";
    dog.pedigree = sg1.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? @"da" : @"nu";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
cellParinti.segmentedControl.tag = 2;
```

I think this should be

```
cellPedigree.segmentedControl.tag = 2;
```

It is a typo in your code, which is preventing you from getting the correct tag.

Comment: You can accept the answer, so that it does not show up as unanswered else where.